# What is the most idiomatic way to express this query with SQAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Essentially I have a SQLAlchemy query that looks like this:

```
foos = Foo.query.filter(Foo.expiration < cutoff)
valid_foos = []
for foo in foos:
    last_bar = foo.bars.order_by('created_at desc').first()
    if last_bar.state != 'fatal':
        valid_foos.append(foo)
```

The goal being to select all the foos for which the first related bar's state is not "fatal". It seems like subqueries might help here. However, I'm struggling to grasp how I can express `last_bar = foo.bars.order_by('created_at desc').first()` in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and most versatile way of doing it is using [`Hybrid Attributes`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) extension. When you extend you model as per below:

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"
    # ...

    @hybrid_property
    def last_bar_state(self):
        _last_bar = self.bars.order_by(Bar.created_at.desc()).first()
        return _last_bar.state

    @last_bar_state.expression
    def _last_bar_state_expression(cls):
        q = (select([Bar.state.label("state")])
                .where(Bar.foo_id == cls.foo_id)
                .order_by(Bar.created_at.desc())
                .limit(1)
                ).label("last_bar_state_sub")
        return q
```

you will be able to use `last_bar_state` both in-memory, as well as in the query:

```
foos = session.query(Foo).filter(Foo.expiration < cutoff)
foos = foos.filter(Foo.last_bar_state != 'fatal').all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to find the latest Bar for each Foo.  Then use that to join and filter Bar when querying Foo.

```
sub = db.session.query(
    Foo.id,
    db.func.max(Bar.created_at).label('latest')
).join(Foo.bars).group_by(Foo.id).subquery()

foos = db.session.query(Foo).join(Bar, db.and_(
    Bar.foo_id == sub.c.id,
    Bar.created_at == sub.c.latest
)).filter(Bar.status != 'fatal').all()
```

This will not select Foo if it has no Bar, you can use an outer join instead for that.